# Using REST PUT in C#

Tags: c#, rest

I am working with a REST API and I am trying to do a `PUT` method to it. I found this code I was going to give a try:

```
    static void Main()
    {
            string xml = "<xml>...</xml>";
            byte[] arr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost/");
            request.Method = "PUT";
            request.ContentType = "text/xml";
            request.ContentLength = arr.Length;
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            string returnString = response.StatusCode.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(returnString);
    }
```

One thing I want to do if possible, and can't seem to find anything about it. I would like to pass the data of text fields so, `txtEmail.Text`, `txtFirstName.Text`, etc. Is this possible? If, so how would I go about doing this? Does this code look like it would work? Unfortunately the API I'm working with has very very little documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what the expected XML looks like? These fields would probably go somewhere in the XML.

Comment: Well you'd include the data within the XML... preferrably by building it using LINQ to XML or something similar, rather than just as a string. That code looks like it *might* work, although you should absolutely have `using` statements for the stream and the response. It's hard to say what you're looking for as an answer...

Comment: I would recommend giving a library like RestSharp a try http://restsharp.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code lines

```
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);
dataStream.Close();
```

do write something to the remote website. The request stream is the way to provide data to the server, so you would create a string / object that you write to the stream to transfer to the server. In your example `<xml>...</xml>` is sent to the server.